# Qt 4.7: QUndoCommand missing?

Tags: qt4, qt-creator

> ../browser/bookmarks.h:48: fatal error: QtWidgets/QUndoCommand: No
>   such file or directory

That's the compile output when I try to load

```
#include <QtWidgets/QUndoCommand>
```

Where do you find this and how do you include it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mat's answer does not cover all the possible corner cases or root causes.

I encountered the same error message "fatal error: QtWidgets/QUndoCommand: No such file or directory" while trying to compile http://fritzing.org/download/0.7.7b/source-tarball/fritzing-0.7.7b.source.tar.bz2  in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

The solution for me was to first install the missing dependency packages, which were:

libqt4-dev libqt4-core  libqt4-qt3support

After that, I could successfully perform the qmake, make, sudo make install dance...

Answer (score 2):

`QUndoCommand` is in the `QtGui` module. You should not need to put a path in your `#include` directive. This should just work if you're using `qmake` or QtCreator:

```
#include <QUndoCommand>
```